# Website as storage for multimedia needed

Tags: web-services

I've developed an excellent social network in Flash. Now I need a site for downloading/uploading of photos and video. Of course, all uploading must take place on my web site, well, so does downloading. Could you recommend such a site or sites that will let me do the job in return for advertising their site on mine or for money (but not too much, as I only need their site as a storage for my multimedia). Thanks in advance. And merry Christmas to you!

Comment: I think you need to specify what kind of technologies / APIs / infrastructure you need exactly. Seeing as you've developed the social network, defining your needs in detail shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: i will consider any thing that can do what i need

Answer (score 2):

Storage? [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).  You'll need to read up on their integration docs, or use something like [s3sync](http://s3sync.net/) to transfer your files, but it gives you the storage option, without hurting the pocket too much to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is a standard answer, but [Rackspace Cloud Files](http://bit.ly/t71iv) is another good option.  Investigate their systems and pricing to see what fits for you.

Answer (score 0):

An option for the future - eventually [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com) will have an API. If you had users sign up for a free DropBox account then they'd get 2G free storage. If they need more space then they can signup for a premium account. The nice thing with this model is you offload your storage costs to the individual users.  The users, in turn, get all the benefits of DropBox.